# R based Web Scraper for Cabela's using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Maybe slightly out of the ordinary, but I want to track down a particular rifle that I am interested in purchasing. I am familiar with R, so I started down that path, but I'm guessing there are better options.

What I want to do is check a web page hourly to see if the availability has changed. If it has, I get a text message.

I started out using rvest and twilio. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get all the way down to the data that I need.  The page has an "Add to cart" button that isn't shown if the item isn't available using css style display:none.

I've tried various ways of trying to get down to that particular div by using id names, css classes,  xpath, etc, but keep coming up with nothing.

Any ideas?  is it the formatting of the div name? Or do I have to manually dig through each nested div?

EDIT: I was able to find the right xpath to work. But as pointed out below, you can't see the style.

EDIT2 - in the out of stock div, the text "In Select Stores Only" is displayed, but I can't figure out how to isolate it.

```
#Schedule script to run every hour

library(rvest)
library(twilio)

#vars for sms
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxx")
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxx")

#example, two url's - one with in stock item, one without
OutStockURL <- read_html("https://www.cabelas.com/shop/en/marlin-1895sbl-lever-action-rifle?searchTerm=1895%20sbl")
InStockURL <- read_html("https://www.cabelas.com/shop/en/thompson-center-venture-ii-bolt-action-centerfire-rifle")

#div id that contains information on if product is in stock or not
instockdivid <- "WC_Sku_List_TableContent_3074457345620110138_Price &amp; Availability_1_16_grid"
outstockdivid <- "WC_Sku_List_TableContent_24936_Price &amp; Availability_1_15_grid"

#inside the div is a button that is either displayed or not based on availability
instockbutton <- 'id="SKU_List_Widget_Add2CartButton_3074457345620110857_table"'
outstockbutton <- 'id="SKU_List_Widget_Add2CartButton_3074457345617539137_table"'

#if item is unavailable, button style is set to display:none - style="display: none;"

test <- InStockURL %>%
  html_nodes("div")

#xpath to buttons
test <- InStockURL %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//* 
[@id="SKU_List_Widget_Add2CartButton_3074457345620110857_table"]')

test2 <- OutStockURL %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//* 
[@id="SKU_List_Widget_Add2CartButton_3074457345617539137_table"]')

#not sure where to go from here to see if the button is visible or not

#if button is displayed, send email
tw_send_message(
  to = "+15555555555",
  from = "+5555555555",
  body = paste("Your Item Is Available!")
)
```

Comment: Rvest will only scrape the HTML source of a webpage. It is not a web browser that can run JavaScript nor does it calculate CSS properties. Most likely the values you are interested in are updated by scripts running on that page after it loads. If you need to interact with such dynamic pages, then consider using the RSelenium package instead. Or you'll have to reverse engineer the website to see if you can replicate the behavior of the scripts in some other way (not recommended because it can be very fragile).

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the response, I had just figured out the xpath for the buttons and was trying to figure out why they were identical (not containing the display:none property) when I saw your message.  I'll read up on RSelenium!

Comment: @MrFlick RSelenium looks to be way over my head, as well as I'm not sure if it will be able to identify if that button is visible or not.  I do see another way to determine availability. The text "In Select Stores Only" is displayed when the button isn't visible. But I can't figure out how to isolate that so I can use it to trigger my sms.